# UINavigationController Title not Applied

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am wondering why my UINavigationController is not letting me set a title. It lets me change the tint of the navigationBar, but the title and rightBarButtonItem I set just get ignored. Why?

Here's my code:

```
  taps = 0;

  UIView*controllerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

  controllerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

  [controller setView:controllerView];

  [controllerView release];

  navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

  navController.navigationBar.barStyle = 1;

  navController.navigationItem.title = @"Setup";

  UIBarButtonItem*item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissSetup:)];

  navController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;

  [item release];

  [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

  [mp stop];
```

p.s: I know i'm not releasing some of the stuff I alloc'ed, I do that later!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The navigation controller updates the
>   middle of the navigation  bar as
>   follows:
>                If the new top-level view controller has a custom title view,
>   the  navigation bar displays that view
>   in place of the default title view. 
>   To specify a custom title view, set
>   the titleView property of the  view
>   controller’s navigation item.
>                If no custom title view is set, the navigation bar displays a
>   label  containing the view
>   controller’s default title. The string
>   for this label  is usually obtained
>   from the title property of the view
>   controller itself.  If you want to
>   display a different title than the one
>   associated with the
>
> view controller, set the title
>   property of the view controller’s
>   navigation item instead.

You want your UINavigationController to change its title depending on which viewcontroller is currently on top. So the way to go is to set the title in the viewcontrollers you are pushing onto the viewControllers array.

And by the way: I don't think navigationcontrollers are supposed to be presented modally:

> Because the UINavigationController
>   class inherits from the
>   UIViewController class, navigation
>   controllers have their own view that
>   is accessible through the view
>   property. When deploying a navigation
>   interface, you must install this view
>   as the root of whatever view hierarchy
>   you are creating. For example, if you
>   are deploying the navigation interface
>   by itself, you would make this view
>   the main subview of your window. To
>   install a navigation interface inside
>   a tab bar interface, you would install
>   the navigation controller’s view as
>   the root view of the appropriate tab.

Comment: how do I set the view Controllers title?

Comment: Actually Apple is fine with presenting navigation controllers modally. There's a section titled "Displaying a Navigation Controller Modally" within the "Combined View Controller Interfaces" section of the View Controller Programming Guide that specifically explains how to do this here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 16):

set: `self.title = @"This is my title";` in the **viewController**

(or in your case set `controller.title = @"this is my title";`)